# Weback manifest file doesn't compile to es5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Recently our build has stopped working on IE11 due to the fact the webpack manifest file has `.includes` in it which IE11 can't run.

I have dug into this and found `react-datepicker` uses `.includes()` in it's code but in our `main.app.js` file it converts it so nothing is in there, it is only in the manifest file.

If I remove the manifest file from our webpack, the error moves to the `main.app.js`file saying `object doesn't support property or method includes`. This error is coming from camelCase.js from `redux-actions`. I feel this is red herring but not entirely sure.

I am not sure if this is a webpack issue or a babel, or the plugin error.

How do I resolve this?

**Steps I have done so far**:

I have locked react to version 16.3.0 in our package.json.

I downgraded the `react-datepicker` plugin.

I have removed the manifest file from being loaded.

I have tried updating `redux-actions`.

I have tried downgrading `redux-actions`

Here is my webpack file:

```
const pkg = require('../package.json');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const appConfig = {
  VERSION: pkg.version,
  OUTPUT_NAME: pkg.config.OUTPUT_NAME,
  DEV_PORT: pkg.config.DEV_PORT
};

const config = {
  mode: 'development',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname),
  entry: {
    app: [
      '../src/index.js',
      '../src/styles/main.css',
      '../index.pug'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/'),
    filename: `scripts/${appConfig.OUTPUT_NAME}.[name].${appConfig.VERSION}.js`,
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.js', '.jsx' ]
  },
  externals: {
    'lottie-web': 'lottie'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1
            }
          },
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'pug-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /node_modules/
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/'),
    port: appConfig.DEV_PORT,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'manifest',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin(`../styles/${appConfig.OUTPUT_NAME}.[name].${appConfig.VERSION}.css`),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: '../src/assets', to: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/assets') },
      { from: '../src/content', to: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/content') }
    ]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ 'template': '../index.pug' })
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to get rid of the library that causes the incompatibility issue with Internet Explorer 11, I would recommend using a polyfill that adds support for the problematic APIs like [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) at runtime.

Probably the most popular solution is the [Babel Polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill).

You can use it by adding the following script tag to your page's HTML code:

```
    <script nomodule src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.26.0/polyfill.min.js" integrity="sha256-WRc/eG3R84AverJv0zmqxAmdwQxstUpqkiE+avJ3WSo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Notice the attribute *nomodule*, this is to make sure that only browsers that do not support ES2015 modules actually load the polyfill – i.e. IE11.

Modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.) will just ignore the script tag and not burden your users with an additional download.

Comment: Ahh man you GENIOUS!! that worked a treat!! thank you so much. been pulling my hair out all day with this one

Comment: Very glad to help, I ran into a similar issue the other day, and this helped me